# php imagecolorat returns 0. Why?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

Sometimes imagecolorat() returns 0 with some pixels in a PNG I'm analyzing. Why is that?

I looked the pixel and the color really is #111111. So it should return 1118481. Right?

I tried using imagealphablending($img,true) but I still get 0.

Thanks!

```
$img = @imagecreatefrompng($png);

if(!$img){
throw new Exception("Error loading PNG.");
}
var_dump(imagecolorat($img, 37, 625));
```

Result:

```
int 0
```

Comment: @Ninsuo I added part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If image is loaded correctly and you get 0, then it means color is pure black (RGB => 0x000000 => 0)

Answer (score 0):

Because that is the color of that pixel: black (red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0)

If you try it for most other pixels you will get 16777215 (0xFFFFFF), which is white (red = 255, green = 255, blue = 255).

Answer (score 0):

Or the color is black, or I think the image is not loading correctly. At least not the .png you put as an example. Maybe the @ is hiding the error of the image not loading. Its url is redirecting to another, and in that case you should use something like CURL to find the real image.